# Is there a way to basically reload the current form without closing it?

Tags: vb.net

So I'm doing a small maze game in vb.net and when it opens/loads the game form, it tells the picture box I'm using as the player, where to be at the start

```
Private Sub frmlvl1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        pbplayer.Location = New Point(30, 28)
        Me.pbplayer.Hide()

    End Sub
```

and then there is a button that shows the pbplayer, starts a timer and defines the points that the player has at the start. And that timer will take a point every second until it reaches zero or the player reaches the end. After, I wanted to open a msg box that asked the user if he wants to try again or exit/close the game

```
   Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Dim x As Integer
        lblpts.Text = CStr(CDbl(lblpts.Text) - 1)

        If CDbl(lblpts.Text) <= 0 Then

            Timer1.Stop()

            x = MsgBox("You lose" & vbNewLine & "Want to try again?", MsgBoxStyle.RetryCancel, "You Lose")
            If x = 4 Then
        'code to retry
            End If
        End If

    End Sub
```

and what I want to know is if I can refresh or basically if i can redo the form load event without closing the form and opening again, i've tried me.refresh(), me.visible = false and frmlvl1.visible= true from a different form, but no success.

Comment: Not as simply as you think, but yes. You can serialize your class' state and deserialize a default state. But since you don't seem to be using a class to store your state, then your other option is to write a `reset()` method which sets all values back to their defaults.

Comment: _"or basically if i can redo the form load event"_ Yes, that's what you should do. What exactly is the problem? You basically execute the same code you have under `frmlvl1_Load` but to avoid repeating the code, you refactor it into a separate method (e.g., `ResetGameState()`) then you call it in the form's Load event and where you need it again.

Comment: However, `InitializeComponent()` almost certainly does more work than Form_Load and you can't just simply call it. Anything which is set in the designer and not in Form_Load is performed by calling `InitializeComponent()`. Of course, and this is your easiest solution, you can put everything in a `reset()` method as mentioned in both comments above.